# Laravel 5 command php artisan... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I was working on composer and perfect. with artisan methods I created many things.

then he was working on routes and wanted to create a Controller.

php artisan make: controller UsersController

and displays the following error

```
[Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError]
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'
```

I wanted to try commands before if they worked and did not work

you uninstall and install composer and error everywhere, not to update, install etc.

always appears the error  ':'':'':'':'

```
[Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError]
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think its due to the space between 'make:' and 'controller'. I generally use 'php artisan make:controller UserController'.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, but the problem is with all commands with ":"  bd:seed    make:model  etc

Comment: I found an article for a problem which you may relate to https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/problem-with-artisan-parse-error-expecting-identifier-t-string?page=1